# What is the name of the group?

Tags: group-theory, linear-transformations, lie-groups

1. What is the name of the subgroup of the affine plane group generated by the transformations of the form
   $$
   x \mapsto  a \begin{pmatrix}  \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta &\cos\theta \end{pmatrix} x+b,
   $$
   $a \in \mathbb{R},$ and $ x,b \in \mathbb{R}^2?$
2. What is relations between the group and its subgroups of rotations, translations and scaling? For example is the group the direct or semidirect  product of such subgroups?

Comment: 1. This is the group of orientation-preserving self-similarities of the Euclidean plane. 2. mixed such product: (scaling $\times$ rotations)$\ltimes$ (translations). Try to prove it!

Comment: May I change here the Euclidean plane  to  the Affine plane?

Comment: Well, it's worse, although a common abuse. An affine plane, technically speaking, has no canonical metric, has no well-defined group of rotations... on the other hand I'd even call it "*orientation-preserving affine self-similarities of the Euclidean plane*".

Comment: $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ for it to be a group. It could also be described as the group of affine maps $z \mapsto sz + w$ for complex numbers $z, s, w$, with $s \neq 0$.